# Alternative to Android mksh's printf?

Tags: android, sh

I'm writing a shell script to be run on Android's mksh. In Bash, I can do the following:

```
printf -v NUMBER "%d" \'"$CHARACTER"
```

The command above converts $CHARACTER into a signed decimal NUMBER. But mksh does not support printf. Is there an alternative solution that just use mksh / ksh's internal commands?

Answer (score 0):

[mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm) **does** support [printf](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/printf.htm) to a certain extent, but is not recommended.

> ```
>  print [-nprsu[n] | -R [-en]] [argument ...]
>         print prints its arguments on the standard output, separated by
>         spaces and terminated with a newline. The -n option suppresses the
>         newline. By default, certain C escapes are translated. These in-
>         clude these mentioned in Backslash expansion above, as well as
>         '\c', which is equivalent to using the -n option. Backslash expan-
>         sion may be inhibited with the -r option. The -s option prints to
>         the history file instead of standard output; the -u option prints
>         to file descriptor n (n defaults to 1 if omitted); and the -p op-
>         tion prints to the co-process (see Co-processes above).
>
>         The -R option is used to emulate, to some degree, the BSD echo(1)
>         command which does not process '\' sequences unless the -e option
>         is given. As above, the -n option suppresses the trailing newline.
>
>  printf format [arguments ...]
>         Formatted output. Approximately the same as the printf(1), utili-
>         ty, except it uses the same Backslash expansion and I/O code and
>         does hot handle floating point as the rest of mksh. This is not
>         normally part of mksh; however, distributors may have added this
>         as builtin as a speed hack. Do not use in new code.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to for mksh to use a builtin printf, mksh needs to be built with printf.c and the build environment variable USE_PRINTF_BUILTIN=1 needs to be set, which isn't recommended. Then it will have printf. If you're planning on distributing this, making it portable, then this probably isn't what you want to do. Instead I would use "busybox printf" which is safer. Most devices have busybox, but to truly make your script portable, you'll want to use mksh's "print" function instead.